# Relation between excess pressure of a spherical droplet and its vapour pressure

Tags: pressure, surface-tension

Suppose we are given vapour pressure **P** and surface tension **T** of a liquid at a particular temperature.

What will be the radius **r** of the smallest spherical droplet that can be formed without evaporation?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the [Kelvin equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kelvin_equation) to find the vapour pressure above a curved surface in terms of that of a flat surface.